# Double Click Android

Tags: android, click, double

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que tem uma lista em um `RecyclerView` e a ideia é que a pessoa escolha um ou mais produtos dessa lista e mude de cor para mostrar que esta selecionado, mas no caso da pessoa escolher errada, ela da um duplo click. Consegui fazer funcionar usando um `setOnClickListener` no viewHolder, dai quando seleciono algum produto ele muda de cor. Tentei chamar também `setOnLongClickListener` até funciona, testei com duas corres diferentes, mas não fica tão fácil usar, se tiver como configurar para mudar o tempo do Click longo pode ser uma opção também. Se alguém tiver algum exemplo de como implementar a função onClick em uma outra classe, ou se já existe uma classe que posso usar. Qualquer informação pode ser útil. Obrigadooo

Comment: Pode explicar melhor. Não entendi a razão para querer o double click. Normalmente o primeiro click selecciona, caso se tenha enganado clica novamente e de-selecciona.

Comment: Sim, você entendeu certo. Assim também é uma boa opção, como verifico se foi clickado para não selecionar, faço isso com o setOnClickListener mesmo?

Comment: Depende de como você está a fazer para seleccionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click não faz parte do universo mobile, apenas de desktop com uso de mouse, usuários não estão acostumados com isso nos aplicativos, é uma péssima decisão de UX utilizar essa abordagem em mobile.

Uma das melhores forma é como a da imagem a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ativar a multi seleção o usuário usa o long press e com um toque seleciona ou cancela a seleção dos itens da lista, Abra o app Gmail e verifique como funciona, a maioria dos app funcionam dessa forma.